# Jquery ui containment x1, x2

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have studied the jQuery ui documentation in relation of containment:
http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-containment

and I do not understand:

```
{ containment: [ x1, y1, x2, y2 ] }
```

It seems that the distance is calculated in relation of the document and not the parent of the draggable? Can someone explain how it works?

```js
 var x1 = 0; // farthest to left it can go?
 var x2 = 100; // farthest to right it can go?
 var y1 = 0; // farthest to top it can go?
 var y2 = 0; // farthest to bottom it can go?

$( ".blue" ).draggable(
 { axis: "x" },
  
 { containment: [ x1, y1, x2, y2 ] }
  
);
```

```css
#parent {
 position:relative;
 margin:0 auto;
 width:300px; height:300px;
 border: 1px #ccc solid;
}

.blue { 
 float:left;
 display:inline-block;
 width:30px; height:30px;
 margin:10px;
 background:blue;
 cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
 <div class="blue"></div>
    <div class="blue"></div>
    <div class="blue"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the containment you have 4 options , as the documentation says

- **Selector**
- **Element**
- **String**
- **Array**

For the **Array** options you can set the coordinates (forming a square or rectangle) in which objects can move.

[image]

Example : `containment: [ 0, 0, 100, 100 ]` , is a square of 100*100px. in this area the objects can move

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/w7L85558/) . the objects can move on a square of 100*100px

If you set this `containment: "parent"`

the objects can move only inside the square with gray border

Comment: this numbers are in relation to the document?

Comment: if you use the Array options , YES ! look the jsfiddle example

Comment: is there a way to make it in relation to the original position that each one has?